# Why don't processes die after page load? - Django

Tags: python, django, memory, garbage-collection

It seems logical to me that processes should die and memory be cleared after the python scripts have run and the HTTP response has been sent.

however It seems I have four processes running, one of which is using over 100MB of memory.

It seems like way too much for what I am doing. Is there some garbage collector settings I need to configure or something?

Comment: It may be relevant to know how your site is deployed (server and such).

Comment: @Adam : using webfaction as host - apache mod_wsgi - no database set up yet.

Answer (score 2):

mod_wsgi keeps loaded python process in memory to speed up any further requests. That is absolutely normal/

Comment: Awesome. How do I make it stop?

Comment: To clarify: nothing should be stored in memory except possibly the .css

Comment: Python is not PHP. In PHP your application is thrown away on every request. Not so with Python. Thus, excessive memory usage is going to be because of your application code and how you do stuff. You need to be asking why your application code is taking so much memory as it is the real problem here. Go read http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/01/12/what-php-deployment-gets-right/

Comment: css in memory? What are you talking about? On topic, you can fiddle with apache's MaxRequestsPerChild option, then your application became dead slow because it'll load all code on each request.